# Only allow one item to be selected in a React Native FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm current designing an app that requires that requires a teacher to be picked from a given list. However, I am currently stumped on how to only allow a user to pick one item from the given FlatList, and if the user selects another item in the list, it deselects the prior selection. The app uses React-Native's FlatList component and the primary function of concern is the TeacherList component, I would really appreciate any solutions!

````
function ListTeacher( {id, name, selected, onSelect} ) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.teacherName}
      onPress={() => onSelect(id)}
      >
        <Text style={[styles.teacherName, { color: selected ? '#44B0F2' : (theme == 'dark' ? 'white' : 'black') }]}> {name} </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}


const TeacherList = (props) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(new Map());

  const onSelect = React.useCallback(
    id => {
      const newSelected = new Map(selected);

      newSelected.set(id, !selected.get(id));

      setSelected(newSelected);
    },
    [selected],
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={teachers}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <ListTeacher
            id={item.id}
            name={item.name}
            selected={!!selected.get(item.id)}
            onSelect={onSelect}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        extraData={selected}
      />
    </View>
  );
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need `new Map()` in this case, you just simply want to store a user choice in a variable. For example

```
const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(null);
const onSelect = (id) => {
 setSelected(id);
}
<ListTeacher
        id={item.id}
        name={item.name}
        selected={item.id === selected}
        onSelect={onSelect}
 />
```

Comment: hey, that was an awesome and simple idea, thanks a lot!